# Firebase FQuery how do you detect when at the end of a list of nodes

Tags: firebase

How do I detect when I have finished processing all found nodes when doing a query?  In the following example, I do some processing on each encountered node.  When I reach the "end" of the list I would like to be able to detect this so I know it's finished.

```
FQuery* messageListQuery = [m_firebaseRef queryLimitedToNumberOfChildren:100];
[messageListQuery observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded andPreviousSiblingNameWithBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot, NSString *prevNodeName) {
    // 1. Do interesting stuff with the snapshot data
    // 2. I want to detect when I'm at the end of the list so I know when I'm done processing the list.
}];
```

Here is the example use case.  I would like to load the latest 100 messages in the background.  Once the messages have been loaded, I would like to update the UI.  However, I'm not sure how I know all the messages have been loaded given there might be less then 100 messages in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to read all the messages up front by using the observeSingleEventOfType and then iterating over the children.

```
[m_firebaseRef observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog( @"Name %@ with %d children.", snapshot.name, snapshot.childrenCount );

    for( FDataSnapshot *child in snapshot.children )
    {
        NSDictionary *msgData = child.value;

        NSString *message      = msgData[kFirebaseLiveChatFieldMessage];
        NSString *gamerTag     = msgData[kFirebaseLiveChatFieldGamerTag];
        NSString *gameCenterId = msgData[kFirebaseLiveChatFieldGameCenterId];
        NSLog( @"Preload = %@ (%@): %@", gamerTag, gameCenterId, message );
    }
}];
```